# Smart Client and Web App simultaneous development

Tags: .net, web-applications, smartclient

What are the strategies and tools to be used, if an Application that is being developed needs to have Web Client and Smart client. Does Smart Client Software Factory or related applications blocks ease such developmental path? The environment is .Net 3.5

Please suggest the direction based on these priorities

1. Reuse of code
2. Development or Executional ease
3. Maintenance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silverlight and WPF are quite similar and you should be able to achieve an extremely high degree of code re-use between the two. See this [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc895632.aspx).

It will get even better in the next version.

Answer (score 0):

Look for Model View Presentor Pattern...If done correctly, you will only need to implement multiple views and rest of the stuff will be reused!

Comment: I understand Model View Presenter pattern. The issue is the container, for Web Client it has to be hosted on IIS which is not the case for Smart client. The more accurate question would be is there a Container or AppServer mechanism that would let me achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use Silverlight? If yes, you can have the same client in web and in desktop (using the new Silverlight 3 out of the browser experience)

If no, you can reuse all business logic in the server and expose the functionality via webservices.
This way your system is testeable and you only have to recode the different client UIs.